# How should the accumulator and current arguments for reduce() be typed?

Tags: typescript

How should the accumulator and current arguments to reduce be typed?

```
interface CountriesContinent {
  continent: string;
  countries: string[];
}

interface ZebraInCountry {
  countryName: string;
  population: number;
}

interface ContinentCount {
  continent: string;
  population: number;
}

export const getAnimals = async (
  zebraInCountry: ZebraInCountry[],
  countriesByArea: CountriesContinent[]
): Promise<ContinentCount[] | null> => {
  return countriesByArea.map((obj: CountriesContinent) => {
    const { continent, countries } = obj;
    return zebraInCountry
      .filter(obj => countries.includes(obj.countryName))
      .reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const population = acc.population + cur.population;
        return { population, continent };
      });
  });
};

const zebraInCountry = [
  { countryName: "Nigeria", population: 100 },
  { countryName: "Ghana", population: 200 },
  { countryName: "Sudan", population: 300 },
  { countryName: "North America", population: 400 },
  { countryName: "South America", population: 100 }
];
const countriesByArea = [
  { continent: "Africa", countries: ["Nigeria", "Ghana", "Sudan"] },
  { continent: "America", countries: ["North America", "South America"] }
];

const zebraPerArea = getAnimals(zebraInCountry, countriesByArea);

console.log(zebraPerArea);
```

The error I'm getting is on the reduce arguments of acc and cur

```
Argument of type '(acc: ZebraInCountry, cur: ZebraInCountry) => { population: number; continent: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: ZebraInCountry, currentValue: ZebraInCountry, currentIndex: number, array: ZebraInCountry[]) => ZebraInCountry'.
  Property 'countryName' is missing in type '{ population: number; continent: string; }' but required in type 'ZebraInCountry'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce accepts a Generic parameter that specifies its accumulator type.
Also is it accepts the initial value as the second parameter.

```
  const { continent, countries } = obj;
  
  return zebraInCountry
    .filter(obj => countries.includes(obj.countryName))
    .reduce<ContinentCount>((acc, cur) => {
      const population = acc.population + cur.population;
      return { population, continent };
    }, {population: 0, continent});
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsCu4rAgZw3FAnGQG8AoZG5BdYkUsALmXzFxAHMBua2vWyc8%20Nhy7cA2gF1%20NAL4CBoSLEQoAWhABGUOAEkQGYVACeFATSE4zAOTgBbCOJE95tAA7pPmADZwYMAMbCCYjjrQHko0KuDQ8EhoDEFM4CZkVLR0KSTgrpIeNN6%20AUEhyGERUQIxyAIQAB7eUGA5IBzI3BBgAIIgwI5wfvjIALzIcPhmIAjIABRWyABeuvpGGZxmbNp6hsZYtrIANEs2IgQAQma9UBBwbJu4BESpzLICAJRsAApQ6I5gPgIAAeV55MCbWTIAA%20lX8fgAfONkVlaHcwJgoCAcqZRNdbvcAHRDTzzeboHQAK0ehwuhFyaTAnxRlmy1gYnXI7Te4GOuJwomQCnGyEpVKKtCWNAxWJxqz2Gzp5mltCJMGAfjUFOprPOz3wRNACD8mAAJgQdVSifr7E4IJ9PqqaES7mbMEgwYzmJtEeTEAh%20QgsSyxqjnYJOW0Sv5AsEcRMA0SY2V48gANR0LHJnyx8ogSXs5Cy7EUZApuMMIPesgKQu0BT88gV-NsAAM1cYzAUn0lPeiHgE9A6bQV6wOpgsEykS25toczjYACI7MBurg4Ev%20S342wAIxttvC07ZOfKu2L5BLgDiAAs4CBN9vc6mKgAmQ-H2cCrYLlxXgBlc0Hy3csX0rEA2AAZk-Rtv3ne1lzsdBWlvZBemcXAECfMDSggtgABZYJPWgz0nP9lwArAwDQjDoGAbDQJ3CoDyPOo5CHKMfwNAk7jgUUZ1PHkIWXXoYCwnD9VENgpBXNd6Jwm970fUClyAs0QJkL8hOHXlWCvOiJNAqSCBklcUJo9DMIYxSqMwSzDJspctPYwcORHFY1jgH5oEJfiJm6PoBiGEZ5jHfYnjMas8SuG4%20N7ZR3PwdA-AgIk-HQbgwq8nyoD83sgA)